# MVC: session InProc vs Stateserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

Trying to hunt this down all day.

I can get sessions to work if I used a "StateSever".  Holds a session from controller to controller and on refresh.  If I use "InProc" the session lives from controller to controller but on refresh it dies [null].  The timeout should not be an issue because I run it immediately.

Any help on this is appreciated.  I really don't want to use stateserver...at least until I understand why this is happening.

Web config

```
<!--<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="1440" mode="InProc"/>-->
  <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="1440" mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"/>
```

Controllers

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionVal"] = "Test";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LoginSuccess()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Views

```
@{
Layout = "";
}
<h2>Login</h2>
<a href="/Login/LoginSuccess">Go Here</a>
```

2nd view

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
Session:  @Session["SessionVal"]
```

Comment: Are you running on Web Farm or Web Garden?

Comment: No I am running locally right now...dev PC

Comment: Could you remove **sessionState**  tag completely from web.config and debug it again?

Comment: I hope this makes sense.  I disabled the session state in web config.  I put a DateTime in the session   The first time I run the project it displays the session.  I hit F5 and it remakes the session.  I continue to hit F5 and it holds.  I enabled stateserver and do the same process but it never remakes the session on the first refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I disabled the session state in web config. I put a DateTime in the
>   session The first time I run the project it displays the session. I
>   hit F5 and it remakes the session. I continue to hit F5 and it holds.
>   I enabled stateserver and do the same process but it never remakes the
>   session on the first refresh.

By default, sessionState is **InProc** mode. **InProc** means Session are stored in memory on the Web server. *If you debug in Visual Studio, it will be your local computer's memory.*

Since memory is not a persistent storage, the sessionState is clearned up by Garbage Collector as soon as your application is stopped.

The bottom line is **it is by design** and there is nothing you can do about it.

If you want to persistent the sessionState even after application is stopped, you need to use **StateServer** or **SQLServer**.

Answer (score 1):

InProc literally means *in process*. It lives and dies with the process it's running on. IIS Express is a throwaway server - quite literally. Visual Studio starts and stops IIS Express all the time for a number of different reasons. For example, every time you stop debugging, by default, IIS Express is killed (though that can be changed on a project by project basis).

Long and short, InProc sessions are unstable even with real IIS on a server. They're that much more so on IIS Express on a local dev box. If you need or want stability of session data between requests, then you need to use something other than InProc.